# Does GWT Layout Panels have to fill the browser width and height?

Tags: gwt, layout

Does GWT Layout Panels have to fill the browser width and height? Or is there any way to have for instance a DockLayoutPanel to have a width of 90%?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this:

```
dockLayoutPanel.setWidth("90%");
dockLayoutPanel.setHeight("90%");
```